# Understanding WP

Tags: hooks

Sorry if this is a newbie question. For designing a woocommerce catalog page i usually copy woocommerce template folder into theme folder and start editing that (overriding template). I see there are these hooks at this page:

```
/**
* woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
* @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
```

& i wonder why would somebody hook into this action for placing something here (markup, query from database, ...) instead of place it just there in this file?

Answer (score 1):

The reason hooks ( Filters and Actions ) are in these templates is specifically so you don't need to copy the templates into your theme folder.

The biggest issue with copying WooCommerce templates into your theme is that often time whenever WooCommerce updates they also update the templates. Then you'll need to bring your changes from the old template into the new template and ensure everything works accordingly so that the overwritten file 'plays nice' with any other Woo changes.

The idea with these hooks is that you should be able to move them around in a different order ( should you need a different layout ) or replace the output with something you may need. The `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` gives you access to modify the result count and ordering filters. Maybe you don't want to show result count - so we can remove it like so:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
```

The next big hurdle is finding out what each hook does and how you can use them to your advantage.